# not able to post in custom time zone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

```
    $usersTimezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Vancouver');

      $l10nDate = new DateTime($date);

     $l10nDate->setTimeZone($usersTimezone);

        $msg_time = $l10nDate->format('h:i A M d',time());
```

Not sure where is the mistake... if i put `$msg_time = date('h:i A M d',strtotime($row["date_time"]));` everything is working but my server time and my country time is not the same. so I need to post data in db in my own time zone to calculate.

Comment: What does `$date` contain? Also, why do you pass `time()` to the `format` method? It only takes one argument, a format string. Further, you can pass the `DateTimeZone` as the second argument to `DateTime` (there is no reason to call `setTimeZone` after it has been instantiated).

Comment: okay as far as I've got this, $msg_time = strtotime($row["date_time"]); and returning me the time in srttotime, but not getting how to show this with local timezone..

Answer (score 0):

On top of your PHP files, add this

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Vancouver');
```

Or in your MySQL INSERT you can add this, that is if you use current_timestamp

```
SET time_zone = 'America/Vancouver';
```